# Display comments alone from Facebook post id iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

my code to fetch the message from Facebook.. this code fetches the comments along with id likes and comment likes.. i need to fetch the name and comments alone..
thank you in advance pls help me in that..

```
 NSString *url1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"10203405506644140/comments"];            
 [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:url1   
                                 parameters:NULL
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {


                      FBGraphObject *postDetails = result;
                      NSLog(@"--comments--->%@",postDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the comment message from result by objectForKey:@"message" in a loop.
To refer the field in receiver object please go through iOS section of this link. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments/